# Error with cross validation and lasso regularization for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, cross-validation, glmnet, lasso-regression

I want to create a 5-fold CV logistic regression model with lasso regularization, but I get this error message: `Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:`.

I started with logistic regression with lasso regularization by setting `alpha=1`. This works. I expanded from [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156098/cross-validating-lasso-regression-in-r).

```
# Load data set
data("mtcars")

# Prepare data set 
x   <- model.matrix(~.-1, data= mtcars[,-1])
mpg <- ifelse( mtcars$mpg < mean(mtcars$mpg), 0, 1)
y   <- factor(mpg, labels = c('notEfficient', 'efficient'))

#find minimum coefficient
mod_cv <- cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, family='binomial', alpha=1)

#logistic regression with lasso regularization
logistic_model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family = "binomial",
                         lambda = mod_cv$lambda.min)
```

I read that the `glmnet` function already does 10-fold cv. But I want to use 5-fold cv. So when I add that modification using `n_folds` to `cv.glmnet`, I can't find the minimum coefficient nor can I just make the model when modifying `trControl`.

```
#find minimum coefficient by adding 5-fold cv
mod_cv <- cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, family='binomial', alpha=1, n_folds=5)


#Error in glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, #lambda = lambda,  : 
#  unused argument (n_folds = 5)

#logistic regression with 5-fold cv
    # define training control
    train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# train the model with 5-fold cv
model <- train(x, y, trControl = train_control, method = "glm", family="binomial", alpha=1)

#Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
#    Accuracy       Kappa    
#Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
# 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
# Median : NA   Median : NA  
# Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
# 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
# Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 # NA's   :1     NA's   :1
```

Why does the error arise when I add 5-fold cv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:
1) the `n_folds` argument in `cv.glmnet` is actually called `nfolds` and 2) the `train` function takes no `alpha` argument. If you fix these your code works:

```
# Load data set
data("mtcars")
library(glmnet)
library(caret)

# Prepare data set 
x   <- model.matrix(~.-1, data= mtcars[,-1])
mpg <- ifelse( mtcars$mpg < mean(mtcars$mpg), 0, 1)
y   <- factor(mpg, labels = c('notEfficient', 'efficient'))

#find minimum coefficient
mod_cv <- cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, family='binomial', alpha=1)

#logistic regression with lasso regularization
logistic_model <- glmnet(x, y, alpha=1, family = "binomial",
                         lambda = mod_cv$lambda.min)



#find minimum coefficient by adding 5-fold cv
mod_cv <- cv.glmnet(x=x, y=y, family='binomial', alpha=1, nfolds=5)


#logistic regression with 5-fold cv
# define training control
train_control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# train the model with 5-fold cv
model <- train(x, y, trControl = train_control, method = "glm", family="binomial")
model$results
#>  parameter  Accuracy     Kappa AccuracySD   KappaSD
#>1      none 0.8742857 0.7362213 0.07450517 0.1644257
```

Comment: if `train` can't take `alpha`, does that mean you cannot have lasso regularization (I'm using it in this case to pair down the hundreds of variables in my real dataset) in addition with cv? So I either have to pick lasso or cv?

Comment: Yes you can, like this: `model <- train(x, y, trControl = train_control, method = "glmnet", family="binomial", 
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, lambda = 1))`

Comment: brilliant! thanks a lot! I'm just starting to learn about logistic functions and this was very helpful to me! :D